# wordpress: how to extract array of custom fields on a page

Tags: wordpress, field

i have a private page that has a series of custom fields.  what i'd like to do is be able to discover how many of these fields are filled and then populate a sidebar based on the contents of the fields.  i have a block of code that works, but it always looks for those four fields specifically and if there's nothing in there, it's just displays an empty block.

here's the code i'm wanting to condense and make smarter:

```
    <li class="sponsorSlot">
        <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_01_uri', true); ?>" title="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_01_uriTitle', true); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_01_image', true); ?>">
        </a>
    </li>       
    <li class="sponsorSlot">
        <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_02_uri', true); ?>" title="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_02_uriTitle', true); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_02_image', true); ?>">
        </a>
    </li>       
    <li class="sponsorSlot">
        <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_03_uri', true); ?>" title="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_03_uriTitle', true); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_03_image', true); ?>">
        </a>
    </li>       
    <li class="sponsorSlot">
        <a href="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_04_uri', true); ?>" title="<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_04_uriTitle', true); ?>">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/<?php echo get_post_meta(158, 'sponsor_04_image', true); ?>">
        </a>
    </li>
```

you'll see what i'm trying to do.  it would be nice if it didn't matter if there were 1 or 8 entries, it would populate what was there without having to explicitly specify.  my thoughts were to build an array and then just step through the array to build the elements i need.

thanks all!

WR!

Comment: as a quick addendum: no jQuery, no plugins, just code please.  thx.  WR!

Comment: will the post id be 158 always ?

Comment: in essence, yes.  it's the ID of the page with all the fields.  it's not accessible from users POV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add an if condition to check the existence of the custom field .

Something like

```
<?php  if((get_post_meta(158, "sponsor_01_uri", true)) || (get_post_meta($post->ID, "sponsor_01_uriTitle", true))) { ?>
```

yeah you can loop through the values returned by get_post_meta(), but as per documentation by default it returns an array of all values of the key you specify, but you are overriding it by specifying `$single` to `FALSE`.

Comment: this is headed in the right direxion, i'd like to be able to check if there we can do this without having to directly specify a unique custom field name.  so instead of "sponsor_01_uri", "sponsor_02_uri", &c. it's just 4 instances of "sponsor_uri" on the page... which we then query how many of them there are and populate from that.  does that make sense?  WR!

Comment: ...on second read, maybe this is exactly what you're saying...?  have to process this a bit...  WR!

Comment: okay.  processed.  i just wasn't reading the codex correctly.  your example helped set me straight.  thank you very much.  :)  WR!